# Microsoft Cognitive Search Services offline?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Are the cognitive services offline?

I am getting the following error in all my API calls.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?.....
```

Anyone else facing this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So now it seems like the API is back online.